# R - use indices and content of list to merge two dataframes [R]

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, dataframe, apply

Perhaps bloody obvious, but new to R. My two dataframes to be merged:

```
longtext <- c("bla bla burp bla blub", "blah bladd", "blablaz burp")
txt <- data.frame(longtext)
queries <- c("burp", "blah")
query <- data.frame(queries)
```

I performed a search for the strings in `query` within the longer text strings in `txt`. The matches were saved in a list of style:

```
matches <-list(c(1,3), c(2))
```

The first index of the list `matches`, e.g [[1]] refers to the first row in `query`. The content of `matches` in the first row (1,3) refers to search hits row 1 and 3 in `txt`. So I want to merge both dataframes by using the indices and content of `matches` to get:

```
queries; longtext        
"burp"; "bla bla burp blah blub"
"burp"; "blablaz burp"
"blah"; "blah bladd"
```

But... my loop over indices and content doesn't work. Is there an easier way with `apply()`? Will feed with lot's of data...

```
matches_long <- data.frame()  
for (i in 1:length(matches)) {
  for (l in 1:length(matches[[i]])) {
    matches_long[[l]] <- data.frame(query[[i]], txt[[matches[[i]][l]]])}}
```

Comment: How big are the two dataframes?

Comment: Only working with samples so far but probably >100.000

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me like you could just add rows to your data set according to the size of `matches` and then just assign the matched values

```
res <- query[rep(seq_along(matches), sapply(matches, length)),, drop = FALSE] 
res["longtext"] <- txt$longtext[unlist(matches)]
res
#     queries              longtext
# 1      burp bla bla burp bla blub
# 1.1    burp          blablaz burp
# 2      blah            blah bladd
```

- in R v 3.2+ you could replace `sapply(matches, length)` with `lengths`

Comment: whooooa this is way too exciting @lengths

Comment: @rawr I would assume you'd like some new additions to base.

Comment: well it's not *that* useful since I work with people and servers who are still on 2.15

Comment: @rawr so for *you* maybe not, but this function shows great improvement both in speed and syntax

Comment: The help says it's faster than `sapply()` but I wonder if it's faster than `vapply()` too. To the benchmark!

Comment: @RichardScriven Amanda did a benchmark against `vapply` and it was about 100 times faster I believe. Look it up in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

@David Arenburgs answer is better, but as I was about to paste this in:

```
names(matches) <- queries
stack(lapply(matches, function(x){longtext[x]}))
```